# How can I fix "Superfluous name server listed at parent" on "producaoaudio.com"?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Superfluous name server listed at parent: `ns1.gabrielsousa.com`.

A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found. This is most likely an administrative error. You should update the parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.

and

Total parent/child glue mismatch.

The parent lists name servers that the child doesnt know about, see details in advanced. This configuration could actually work but breaks very easily if one of these zones change slightly.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glue records you have filed with your domain registrar do not match the nameserver records you have in the DNS zone.

Your registrar has these records:

> ```
> Name Server: ns1.sysadmn.net 81.84.24.93
> Name Server: ns1.gabrielsousa.com 37.59.115.115
> ```

While your DNS records show:

> ```
> producaoaudio.com name server ns1.producaoaudio.com.
> producaoaudio.com name server vps153109.ovh.net.
> ```

These must be changed, so that they match, both in your DNS, and with the registrar.